# How to get the Information if a FrameworkElement is scrolled into sight

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, scroll, frameworkelement

i just want to know if that is possible. I'm using a `ScrollViewer` to scroll. I know a very bad way to do it (ref. to [Scrollviewer and ItemsControl VerticalScrolling into nirvana](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16774511/scrollviewer-and-itemscontrol-verticalscrolling-into-nirvana)) but it is no option to do it that way because there is to much trouble with the user expirience.

Comment: How to get what information?

Comment: If a FrameworkElement is scrolled into sight. Like the title describes.

Comment: Can you climb up the tree to the control's virtualizing stack panel?